# Pagination in a rest view api

Tags: views, 8

How to handle this situation in the Rest Export View as api.

We want to fetch a limit of 20 items in the api and with a load more feature. Currently our api produces hundreds of items.

In the Pager section, I can ofcourse select `Paged output, full pager` and specifiy  `Items to display`, say 20. But how this works in the api? Since its only displaying 20 items, how does load more feature occur? Thanks!

This is my Pager settings.

```
PAGER
Items to display:Full | Paged, 20 items
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply pass the “page” parameter with the request, like ‘api/foo/bar?page=1’. Views will return the next set of results as you increment the page number. You can do the load more interaction however you want on the front end so long as you specify the page and keep track of total results.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It does works in contents, but doesnt seems to be working when using the api response
`http://localhost:8080/api?_format=json?page=2`

Comment: Something else must be wrong then, we are doing this everywhere on a large site. Ensure full pager is selected.

Comment: Also in your URL you have two question marks. After the first question mark, all other query parameters should be apprended with an & ampersand.

Comment: How would someone know that there is a next page? I ideally you'll want to have a parameter where it says `next-page: api/foo/bar?page=2`

Comment: Decoupled front ends can be built and you can pass a total results number in the response so pagers can be constructed based on that. It works for either a load more, infinite scroll, or standard numbered pager.

Comment: @Kevin sorry I missed that part of your answer, that works too.

Comment: Is there a way of adding per page parameter to this..?

Comment: @Kevin but how to see total number of pages or total count of rest export result?